# Table structure for DB2 on an ancient AS/400

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400

We have a VERY old 400, on the order of 10-15 years old, and I need to migrate the data out of it so it can be retired.  I have ODBC connectivity to it through a program called QTODBC that is reporting that the host that I'm connecting to is version 03.01.0000.  I'm trying to access system tables so that I can get table structure data and I've tried various commands that all seem to be written for later versions of DB2.

What were the system tables back way back then?  And how would I pull up schema names, assuming they had them with this old of a version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet for V3R1 will be to use the `DSPFFD FILE(...) OUTPUT(*OUTPUT) OUTFILE(LIB/FILE)` command from a terminal session to create a file of field definitions.

There's a high chance with a system that old that the files may not even be externally described.  This means that the file layout is hardcoded in each program that access the file.  You can recognize this situation if you only find a few fields named F00001, K00001, etc.

Comment: Thank you, James.  I was hoping I could do something at the ODBC level, I'll fire up a 5250 session and see what I can get.  The tables, all 1600 of them (fortunately not all populated), seem to be descriptive, there are also views.  The thing that threw me was that I could find no evidence of DB2 on this box while looking through the licensed program screens.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't provide more information.  I found the jewel case for my old V3R1 softcopy library but the discs are missing.  SC41-3701 DB2/400 Programming is the book you need to get the details.  I assume you couldn't retrieve the information from SYSIBM/TABLES, SYSIBM/COLUMNS, etc?

Comment: James, I have a copy of DB2 v7 for the PC.  Do you think it could directly access the 400 v3?  The technique that I'm using is very clunky: import tables in to Microsoft Access, then export them up to SQL Server.  It wouldn't be bad except there's 1600 tables in the 400 system.

Comment: I've never worked with DB2 on the PC so I can't offer any advice there.  I was able to locate an IBM Redbook [Fast Path to iSeries Client/Server Using iSeries OLE DB Support: SG24-5183](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg245183.html) about using the OLEDB driver with V3R1.  You can use the AS/400 OLEDB driver with DTS/SSIS to drive your transfers directly from SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the table structure quering QSYS2/SYSCOLUMNS tables.

Browse the QSYS2 library for tables and views about indexes and others.

Answer (score 0):

```
describe output select * from creator_schema.tablename
```

This worked for me.